# New Pi Model 4 hangs at most boots

Tags: hdmi, boot-issues, pi-4

Greatings all Pi eaters!

Got the latest Pi "Raspbian Buster full" on a 16 gig SD card but it hangs apx 50% of the time at boot right after log messages disappear.

One monitor has a valid HDMI signal but totally black screen.

The other flashes with warning of no HDMI signal.

If I pull the power ... eventually it goes ok until next reboot.

How can I display boot log or keep on screen to see what happened?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using hdmi0 ?

Comment: `If I pull the power ... eventually it goes ok ` Eh... how does that work? If I pull the power nothing works anymore...

Comment: using both ... dual display ... and of course I imply that I re-connect the power to attempt another boot.

Comment: When I pull the second HDMI ... seems to boot everytime